# HI there, I am writing a simple python to Arduino Bilnk Code with pyfirmata. But the there seems to be an issue

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-uno, firmata, pyfirmata

I want to execute the blink example in Arduino UNO using LED pin 13 (inbuilt)
And I want to use Python to do so....
"I did upload the Standard Firmata code in Arduino using the Arduino IDE"
Then I hopped on to VS code
I tried to create a virtual environment named "pyArdu" and then installed Serial and firmata using pip.
Then in the code I tried accessing the port to which i connected Arduino UNO.
Still the program isn't running.

Here is the code

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import time

board = Arduino('COM4')

iterator = util.Iterator(board)
iterator.start()
while True:
    board.digital[13].write(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    board.digital[13].write(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I tried watching youtube solutions. There is not much of Figmata stuff on it.

I switched from python 3.12.2 to python 3.9.9

Here is the error :

> File "c:\Users\Sparsh\OneDrive\Documents\Skills\PyFirmata\Firstone.py", line 4, in 
> board = Arduino('COM4')
> File "C:\Users\Sparsh\OneDrive\Documents\Skills\PyFirmata\pyArdu\lib\site-packages\pyfirmata_*init*_.py", line 19, in **init**
> super(Arduino, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Sparsh\OneDrive\Documents\Skills\PyFirmata\pyArdu\lib\site-packages\pyfirmata\pyfirmata.py", line 89, in **init**
> self.sp = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, timeout=timeout)
> AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Comment: You appear to have a `serial.py` file somewhere that *isn't* the PySerial module needed by PyFirmata.  I can't tell if it's some script of yours, or some package you installed that has a conflicting name.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to connect some dots.

Answer (score 0):

PyFirmata dosen't support python 3.9.9 in VS code.
So when I tried with ***Python 3.6.3***, it ran pretty much perfectly !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).